# How to specify custom test directory path in truffle-config.js

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

How do I specify a custom **test directory** path in **truffle-config.js**? My test directory is not present at the same level as truffle-config.js, it is residing in a different directory.
Truffle has options to specify custom contracts and migration directory. Similarly, do we have for test directory?

Answer (score 1):

After trying out some things, I found the solution, we have to specify the path of the test directory in the truffle-config.js i.e

```
module.exports = {
    description: 'Test Configuration',
       networks: {
    },
    test_directory: '../test',
    migrations_directory: 'migrations',
  };
```

[Official Truffle documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#contracts_directory) have not mentioned about the custom directory for tests but, this seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/testing-your-contracts#location):

> All test files should be located in the `./test` directory.

---

**UPDATE:**

I found this in the source code (Truffle v4.1.16):

```
  var props = {
    ...
    build_directory: function() {
      return path.join(self.working_directory, "build");
    },
    contracts_directory: function() {
      return path.join(self.working_directory, "contracts");
    },
    contracts_build_directory: function() {
      return path.join(self.build_directory, "contracts");
    },
    migrations_directory: function() {
      return path.join(self.working_directory, "migrations");
    },
    test_directory: function() {
      return path.join(self.working_directory, "test");
    },
    ...
  };
```

Which means that you can do it using `test_directory` (as you've mentioned in a comment).

The documentation that I've linked above is therefore not updated.

Comment: I have kept all files in the test directory, but the directory is not present at the same level as truffle-config. So how can I specify the path to test directory from truffle-config?

Comment: @FLASH: The `./` part implies that this folder must reside **next** to `truffle-config.js`.

Comment: Yes, the `truffle-config.js` and `test` directory has to be at the same level.

Comment: I tried specifying **test_directory: '../path-of-the-test-directory'** in truffle-config.js with the test directory path and it worked. So it seems that we can have a test directory anywhere but, the path needs to be mentioned for the same.

Comment: @FLASH: Yup, you're right, I checked the source code and it's there. The documentation that I've linked is therefore not updated.